# How to escape curly bracket "{" in TYPO3 Fluid template?

Tags: typo3, fluid

I've a mixed HTML / JS template, when I'm working with JS arrays, Fluid tries to make autosubstitutions.

Is there a way to escape curly brackets in Fluid template ?

UPD :

Actual working syntax to escape JS parts is :

```
<script type="text/javascript">/*<![CDATA[*/
/*]]>*/
var llKeyOne = '{f:translate(key:"key1")}';
var llKeyTwo = '{f:translate(key:"key2")}';
/*<![CDATA[*/
var myTranslations = {
  llKeyOne: llKeyOne,
  llKeyTwo: llKeyTwo
};
/*]]>*/</script>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to use

```
<![CDATA[...]]>
```

tags around your JS code.

Comment: Right. I just found the answer of Bastian Waidelich http://forge.typo3.org/issues/8879 Now it works, thanks.

Answer (score 8):

The CDATA solution stopped working in 8.7

I managed to solve the problem using alias in a usecase that heavily mixes javascript and fluid. {l} stands for left (open curly bracket) and {r} stands for right (close curly bracket):

```
<f:alias map="{l: '{', r: '}'}">
    var alter = {};
    <f:for each="{alterDB}" as="a">
        if (!alter[{a.einsatz}]) { alter[{a.einsatz}] = {}; }
        alter[{a.einsatz}][alter[{a.einsatz}].length] = {l} label: "{a.bezeichnung} ({a.kuerzel})", value: {a.uid} {r};
    </f:for>
</f:alias>
```

Answer (score 6):

Since it didn't worked for me in TYPO3 v8.7.16 with the `<![CDATA[]]>` [solution above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17696105/how-to-escape-curly-bracket-in-typo3-fluid-template#17696308), I wanted to share my own solution. My "hack" to escape the brackets is to wrap those with a `<f:format>` viewhelper.

**My goal was to output this in the frontend (400 and swing are fluid variables):**

```
<ul data-animate="{duration:400, easing:'swing'}">
    ...
</ul>
```

**I did this in the Fluidtemplate and it worked perfectly:**

```
<ul data-animate="<f:format.raw>{</f:format.raw>duration: {data.myfield1}, easing:'{data.myfield2}'<f:format.raw>}</f:format.raw>">
    ...
</ul>
```

Answer (score 4):

## Solution working in TYPO3 9.x / 9.5.x

To avoid too much markup around curly braces which has a "*not so nice*" impact on the summary markup (readability and IDE support / highlighting) here an additional solution.

**Possible limitation:**
In our case the fluid template only contained **fluid template variables** within the templates head section followed by the entire markup which is processed/rendered by `angular.js`.

So we've created a partial for the `angular.js` part and included those inside the main fluid template.

**Example:**
[image: Use a partial for the angular.js part and disaple fluid parsing in there]

The included partial file now starts using a [`{parsing off}`](https://usetypo3.com/24-fluid-tips.html#c433) statement (see example below).

**Partial (simplified):**

```
{parsing off} <!-- This solved all our issues -->

<div ng-show="showSlider">
    <div class="slider" data-test="slider-wrapper">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="slide-indicator-mask col-lg-12">
                <div class="slider-scope page-{{firstSlide}}"></div>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a fluid-Variable to add "![CDATA[" into your script.

I use the the tag-notation of fluid in javascript, because the syntax-highlighting works better with it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">/*{startCDATA}*/

var llKeyOne = '<f:translate key="key1" />';
var llKeyTwo = '<f:translate key="key2" />';
var myTranslations = {
  llKeyOne: llKeyOne,
  llKeyTwo: llKeyTwo
};
/*{endCDATA}*/</script>
```

I solved the bracket-problem with TYPO3-fluid and angulars-expressions in my dynamic template in the same way

```
<f:alias map="{ang: {s: '{{', e: '}}'}}">
...    
    <div class="{ang.s}{class}-{subclass}{ang.e}">...
</f:alias>
```

Comment: ...and where does `{startCDATA}` and `{endCDATA}` come from?

Comment: In TYPO3 8.7 for me now works something like that:

    <script type="text/javascript">
         /*<f:format.cdata>*/
          viewConfig: {
        /*</f:format.cdata>*/
                startPage: '<f:uri.page />'
        /*<f:format.cdata>*/
            }
        /*</f:format.cdata>*/
    </script>

It's kinda ridiculous, but at least it does what is expected to.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe too late but I found also one funny solution.

When I was integrating google seach structured data I found there this settings which should go to the template

`<meta itemprop="target" content="https://query.example.com/search?q={search_term_string}"/>`

And this is the easiest way I found for integration there

`<meta itemprop="target" content="https://query.example.com/search?q={<f:format.raw>search_term_string</f:format.raw>}"/>`

Answer (score 0):

The last answer helpt me insert the files public url of an YouTube Video in TYPO3 fluid template using [Video-js](https://github.com/videojs/video.js) with [Video-js YouTube extension](https://github.com/videojs/videojs-youtube).

After adding an new video in fileadmin and posting {file.publicUrl} in fluid returns an error. wrapping it inside f:format will do the job!

`<f:format.raw>{file.publicUrl}</f:format.raw>`

This is the whole code for getting YouTube Videos:

```
<f:if condition="{file.originalFile.properties.extension} == 'youtube'
    <video
        id="vid1"
        class="video-jS"
        data-setup='{ "techOrder": ["youtube"], "sources": [{ "type": "video/youtube", "src": "<f:format.raw>{file.publicUrl}</f:format.raw>"}] }'
    >
    </video>
</f:if>
```

Comment: if you use the inline format (`{file.publicUrl->f:format.raw()}`) it might be easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

For the issue with a data attribute like

```
<ul data-animate="{duration:400, easing:'swing'}">
    ...
</ul>
```

the easiest solution I found was to simply swap single quotes and double quotes, like

```
<ul data-animate='{"duration":"400", "easing":"swing"}'>
    ...
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

on the way to include a newsletter background I had to add Microsoft VML to my fluid. This also has parts that fluid tried to process. My way: I defined a fluid variable:

```
page.10 = FLUIDTEMPLATE
page.10.variables.msxml = TEXT
page.10.variables.msxml.value (
                <!--[if gte mso 9]>
                <v:background xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="t">
                <v:fill type="tile" src="http://reguengo.com.dedi87.your-server.de/fileadmin/templates/imgs/fgp_reguengo_bg.gif" color="#7bceeb"/>
                </v:background>
                <![endif]-->
            )
```

and inserted:

```
<f:format.raw>{msxml}</f:format.raw>
```

voilà